# Модули в yii2 и связь с существующей моделью

Tags: php, yii2, mvc, модульность

Вопрос связан с разработкой [модулей](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-modules.md) в `yii2`.

Предположим, у меня есть модуль `Блог` - авторизованные пользователи могут создавать посты в блоге. Для того, чтобы реализовать этот функционал, я так понимаю, мне надо в модуле создать модель `User` и на ее основе реализовывать авторизацию, разграничение прав и т.д.

Теперь предположим, что я хочу установить этот модуль на сайт (`yii2` приложение), на котором уже реализована своя авторизация и есть своя модель `User`.

Вопрос, собственно, заключается вот в чем - нельзя ли при разработке модуля `Блог` как-то предусмотреть эту ситуацию, чтобы он мог работать с уже имеющейся на сайте моделью пользователей? Ну то есть, пользователь авторизуется на моем сайте - и теперь ему также разрешено создавать посты в блоге.

Comment: Создайте **behavior** или **trait** cо своим функционалом. Который пользователь может легко подключить в свою модель. Либо модель должна наследоваться от вашей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вполне можете использовать в вашем модуле компоненту веб-приложения [**user**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html#$user-detail) -- она предоставляет набор стандартных методов, которые покрывают большинство типовых задач, например:

- `\Yii::$app->user->isGuest` -- узнать авторизован ли текущий пользователь
- `\Yii::$app->user->id` -- ID текущего пользователя
- `\Yii::$app->user->identity` -- конкретный экземпляр класса, описывающий текущего пользователя
- *и т.д.*

Если же вы хотите свести к минимуму обращения к родительскому приложению в модуле, то вполне можно вынести компоненту `user` в конфиг своего модуля:

```
public class BlogModule extends Module 
{
    public $user = 'user';

    /**
     * @return \yii\web\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->{$this->user};
    }        
}
```

Тогда в коде вы сможете обращатья к компоненте `user` вот так:

```
BlogModule::getInstance()->getUser()->isGuest
```

Разграничение прав вы можете сделать в своём модуле полностью независимо (ссылаясь на ID пользователей), либо также использовать, например `authManager` родительского приложения, или добавить его в настройки модуля:

```
public class BlogModule extends Module 
{
    /* @var string $authManager AuthManager component name in parent application */
    public $authManager = 'authManager';

    /**
     * @return \yii\rbac\DbManager
     */
    public function getAuthManager()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->{$this->authManager};
    }       
}
```

Тогда вы можете, например, в миграциях своего модуля прописать создание всех необходимых вам ролей, разрешений и правил. Проверка прав доступа сведется к простому вызову типа:

```
BlogModule::getInstance()->getUser()->can('editPost', ['id' => $postId]);
```

В большинстве случаев в конфиге вашего модуля даже не нужно будет напрямую указывать `user` и `authManager`, т.к. их стандартные названия уже прописаны в дефолтных значениях.

Альтернативный вариант -- создать в модуле свои собственные абстракции, и требовать от приложения их имплеметации, но вряд ли это целесообразно в случае с такими типовыми задачами как аутентификация и распределение прав доступа.

p.s. к стати, рекомендую компонент соединения с базой данных также выносить в настройки модуля, по такой же схеме.

p.p.s. чтобы `getInstance` модуля работал не только в контексте контроллеров (например, если вы планируете использовать модели или компоненты из модуля напрямую), нужно добавить загрузку модуля в `bootstrap` родительского приложения (в конфиге).